# How do I pass parameters to Jobs in Play! Framework 1.2.x?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x, promise

I have a piece of my Play! (1.2.4) application that loads data in from a CSV file and this works fine, but it takes a while, wo I've been trying to farm it off to a Job via the Promise mechanism.  The trouble is, there doesn't seem to be a way to pass input parameters (the CSV file and a string for the type of file), because doJobWithResult is an override of a parameter-less method.

Job looks like :-

```
public class ImportCSV extends Job<string> {
public String doJobWithResult()
{
    do stuff...
    return my_string;
```

}

and is called like :-

```
Promise<String> recordcount = new ImportCSV().now();
String records = await(recordcount);
```

I tried creating a constructor in the Job class that takes those parameters, but then it doesn't trigger when called via the now() method.

Any suggestions on how I can pass the data needed to actually perform the job asynchronously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should:

1. Create `private fields` in your ImportCSV class to hold the params required for the job
2. Initialize these fieds in your Job class constructor (`this.param1 = param1`)
3. Call `new ImportCSV(param1, param2)` to initialize your object
4. Access the private fields in your doJobWithResult() method using `this.param1`

The creation of the Promise is good, you will end with:

```
Promise<String> recordcount = new ImportCSV(param1, param2).now();
String records = await(recordcount);
```

If you have problems with the constructor of your Job class please update your question and add some code.

Comment: I had to copy the params passed to the constructor to the private fields (csvfile = csvfile2, filetype = filetype2), but apart from that, works a treat. Thanks!